# SQL Server replication error 'Publication 'sync' does not exist.'

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm new to SQL Server replication. I'm trying to set up merge pull replication. But I get this error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-ver16

I worked with this guide.

My task is to synchronize data on three servers. So that all three servers have the same data. If something changes on one, on the other two the data was also updated.